# What could cause bcp to ignore the code page flag?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, bcp

I am trying to export data to CSV, with UTF-8 as the desired code page. As explained in the documentation of `bcp`, you can use the flag `-C 65001` for that. As such, my command is as follows:

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.foo" queryout \\directory\csv\bar.csv -c -t; -C 65001 -S servername -T -w
```

I keep running into an odd problem though: Whenever the export is successful, the resulting file has UTF-2 LE BOM (according to Notepad++). Curiously, if I run my same command through an old version of BCP which did not support UTF-8, I get the following error:

```
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]This version of SQL Server Nat
ive Client does not support UTF-8 encoding (code page 65001)
```

This indicates that the command syntax seems to be correct. Nevertheless, when executing it with a version of BCP that came with SQL Server 2016 (or later), the `-C` flag simply seems to be ignored. Similarly, I have noticed that changing the value 65001 to any other value also seems to result in it being ignored.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: The `-w` switch tells BCP to write out data using UTF-16 encoding. As per [bcp Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) _-w is not compatible with -c_.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @AlwaysLearning. However, since `-c` and `-C` are not the same thing, I am not entirely sure. I have tried the same command but without the `-c` flag, but that did not change anything. Am I to understand that `-w` overwrites both `-c` and `-C`?

Comment: Yes, the `-c` and `-C` switches are different. The `-c` switch tells bcp to use byte-sized characters, the `-C` switch is used to specify code pages. The command in your question is conflicted because it uses all three: `-c` `-C` and `-w`. Also, I don't believe SQL Server 2016 supports UTF-8 code pages so you'll need to do one of two things: 1. use `-w` to write out UTF-16 encoded files, or 2. use PowerShell to query the database and write out file data using `Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8` (or use some other tool).